# Multiple image sliders in a single page

Tags: javascript, html

I want two separate image sliders in a single page. I have created two separate sliders, but they are changing on button click. I want the images to be changed automatically without any click. How can I make the slideshow automatic for both the sliders?

```
<div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides1">
        <img src="img/1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1">
        <img src="img/2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1">
        <img src="img/3.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<p>Slideshow 2:</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides2">
        <img src="img/1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2">
        <img src="img/2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2">
        <img src="img/3.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<script>
    var slideIndex = [1, 1];
    var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2"]
    showSlides(1, 0);
    showSlides(1, 1);

    function plusSlides(n, no) {
        showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
    }

    function showSlides(n, no) {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
        if (n > x.length) { slideIndex[no] = 1 }
        if (n < 1) { slideIndex[no] = x.length }
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        x[slideIndex[no] - 1].style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you calling it a CSS slider when it clearly uses JavaScript?

Comment: Both sliders need a unique id or class to give them different options and even in this case I would launch each with its own unique id or class selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` to call the `plusSlides()` function at regular intervals:

```js
setInterval(function() {
    plusSlides(1, 0);
    plusSlides(1, 1);
}, 1000); // Every 1 second
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Zeraora/d9scw1re/

Comment: Addition: I would recommend taking into account with your users that prefer a reduced motion on a website, because they can get really nauseous for hours just by looking at you automatic moving slider. You can read more about it on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion